# Pass in Keys dynamic from app.config file

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, key, app-config

I have the following keys in the config file, I want to pass in the “add key” dynamically to my conn variable from the config file, I can pass in qp.cat.qmgr successful, in my conn variable, I was wondering how I pass the other keys in to my variable do I pass in the next Key from the .config like + "qp.cat.quser", i.e.

```
var conn = new RabbitMqConnection(Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.qmgr") + ("qp.cat.quser") + ("qp.cat.qpassword"));

var conn = new RabbitMqConnection(Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.qmgr"), "theTestingUAT", "catquat"); //this works but "theTestingUAT" and "catquat" is hard coded, dont want them to be hardcoded

    <add key="qp.cat.qmgr" value="thetest:5444" />
    <add key="qp.cat.quser" value="theTestingUAT" />
    <add key="qp.cat.qpassword" value="catquat" />
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
//Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.qmgr")
//Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.quser")
//Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.qpassword")

var conn = new RabbitMqConnection(Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.qmgr"), Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.quser"), Helpers.AppSettings.Get<string>("qp.cat.qpassword"));
```